# Dropdownlist with button when button click popup opened

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

Can you please give me a clue how to do this? I have a `DropDownList`, that `DropDownList` is filled with `ListItems`. After the `DropDownList`, there's a `Button` called *ADD NEW*. When the button is clicked, a popup opened. If an item is not in the `DropDownList`, I wanted to add it. In popup box window there's a `TextBox` and add `Button`.

Basically, If an item is not in `DropDownlist` I want to add it by clicking the *ADD NEW* button.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm going to write that code,but before here i have ask the right direction.NOT the code

Answer (score 1):

Something on the following line...

```
string newItem = textbox1.Text;
if(ddlMyList.Items.FindByText(newItem) == null) //Means item not found
    {
    ddlMyList.Items.Add(new ListItem(newItem));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In popup when you enter the item and press add button just do the following steps:

```
 1. Iterate through all the elements in dropdown and check if item you want to add exist or not
 2. If item does not exist then add it to dropdown using this code:
     yourDropdown.items.Add(newitem);
```